# Excel timeline Conditional formating

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I am trying to create a timeline that is followed by a conditional formatting in the columns. The time in the top left is the actual time as it is now, however it has been rounded to the lower 10 min. 17.45 becomes 17.40. etc.

`(=TIME(HOUR('Year Dashboard'!B3),FLOOR(MINUTE('Year Dashboard'!B3),10),0))`

For some of the times the conditional formatting works, however for some it does not.

`(=AF3+TIME(0,10,0))`

[image]

The below image shows the conditional formatting, where Time is defined by Name Manager as location of E2.

[image]

I hope my question is clear, hope someone can help. thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite follow, do you want to highlight using custom formatting the column that matches the current time?

Comment: that is completely correct.

Comment: It's a floating point problem. I recreated your sheet, and had the same behavior. It worked at first, and then blinked out when I added a row somewhere. My two values for 15:10:00 after the change are 0.631944444444444 and 0.631944444444445. I have to run and can't troubleshoot more. Good luck.

Comment: have you tried rounding?

Comment: yes I tried rounding, but then the times in the cells are not exactly 16:50 but 16:47 for example...

Comment: It's ugly, but you could try breaking the times up into their components and concatenating them. Then you're just doing a string comparison. e.g. =HOUR(A3)&MINUTE(A3)&SECOND(A3)

Comment: This looks like it works, i will post an answer soon.

Comment: @picobit or the OP (Oli) can answer it.. and this question will goes shall be removed from the unanswered list. ( :